# Using Windows Explorer's "Open File" function in Java

Tags: java, windows, swing, file-io, windows-explorer

Using this in Java will open Windows Explorer to the C drive:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:\\"));
```

However, I also need the "Open File" functions highlighted here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNtMj.jpg

Is there a way to implement this in Java (using Windows Explorer, not Swing's FileChooser)?

Comment: That image is the open dialog from MS Word not Windows Explorer. The latter has no _open_ dialog

Comment: Yea just as an example

Comment: You need to be more specific. Windows Explorer has no open dialog whereas there is an open dialog for all MS Office apps

Comment: @JasmineMercier The question is, why?  What's wrong with `JFileChooser`?  Have you tried [`FileDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html)

Comment: Java doesn't have access to the API of Windows applications so you can't invoke those dialogs.

Comment: The program is for non-technical people and I'd like the look to match what they're used to(Windows Explorer, not Swing's FileChooser)

Comment: Then set the L&F to that of the current platform

Comment: @Reimeus I think you need to make that an answer, may be with a little demo code!

Comment: The question is very ok. I don't understand the negative votes. Therefore +1 to compensate for the negative vote.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at using [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) while using the native system's [look & feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/):

[image]

```
public class NativeOpenDialogDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                   ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Open File Example");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                JButton openButton = new JButton("Open");
                openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(frame) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                            // do something
                        }
                    }
                });
                frame.add(openButton);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for finding the problem and solution

Answer (score 2):

We can use JFileChoose,

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int status = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                if (file == null) {
                    return;
                }

                String fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
   ......

            }
```

Comment: (using Windows Explorer, not Swing's FileChooser)